# Issue passing value through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a HTML table on my website where I click on a cell and then am able to edit it.  I am now trying to push the edited value back to my database by using ajax.  I have tested the click to work properly, the content editable to work properly and that ajax is sending to the correct URL by using a simple "hello" on updatedatabase.php and seeing it return through the alert.  When I try to pull the data from ajax to updateddatabase.php is where I am having problems.  I believe that maybe $(this).val() may not be what I want to get the contents of the cell that I just edited with contenteditable?  The reason I say this is because it looks like a blank value is being passed through to the second page.  Here is a chunk of my code for the click / content editable /ajax on the main page:

```
    $('td').click(function(){

        var val=($(this).siblings().first().text());

        var col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));

        $(this).prop('contenteditable', true);

        //var row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());

        //alert('Date: ' + val + ', Column: ' + col);

        $(this).bind('input propertychange', function() {

            //On key stroke

            $.ajax({
              method: "POST",
              url: "updatedatabase.php",
              data: { content: $(this).val() }
            })
              .done(function( msg ) {
                alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
            });

         });
    });
```

and here is what I have sitting on updatedatabase.php.  I kept it simple just to test the value passing through for now.

```
<?php
    if(array_key_exists("content", $_POST)) {

        echo $_POST['content'];
    }

?>
```

Hopefully this is an easy fix as I believe it all may just be with $(this).val()  but I am not sure what I should change it to?  Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: Generally, TD elements have no value, so `val()` wouldn't return anything. Nor do they have an `input` event. Also, binding event handlers inside event handlers, is usually not a very good idea.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Im still learning here, im not sure how to watch the request / response?  Yes I have it uploaded on web hosting.  I have <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> included at the top which I am hoping is also correct for ajax?

Comment: @adeneo  What would be a better way to set the event handlers up?  I am still learning.  The idea is that im loading a Database table into an HTML table on the page.  A cell can be clicked to edit it and now im trying to send the new edited value back into the database.

Comment: Press the F12 key while you're in the browser to open the developer tools. You can watch the request / response under the network tab.

Comment: @JayBlanchard is this what you mean?  Looks like nothing is being passed through if im looking at this right?  Heres a screenshot https://gyazo.com/afc55dcbcdd7eff1dc1b24b06096cb76

Comment: Yep - that is what I mean. When you click on the TD you should see the request and response.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I can find the updatedatabase.php but cannot find anywhere where it tells what is actually supposed to be passed.  It shows a cookie that is encrypted but that is all I see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the problem is that you're not actually capturing the value of the table cell to be edited. Using a new version of jQuery in my sample code I have replaced your `bind()` with `keyup()` as there should not need to be any delegation:

```
$('td').click(function() {
   console.log('clicked');
   $(this).prop('contenteditable', true);

   $(this).keyup(function() { // get the new value as soon as the key is released

     console.log($(this).html());

   });
 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w9e0d5wm/

As mentioned in comments by @adeneo, table cells have no value property which you can get with `val()`. In my example I have used `$(this).html()` to get the text inside the changed `<td>`, but you could also use `.text()`.

You should change `data: { content: $(this).val() }` to `data: { content: $(this).html() }` or `data: { content: $(this).text() }` in order to send a variable value in your AJAX. Now if you watch the console you'll see something posted and something returned.

Comment: This works perfect Jay!  I am still very much a novice and thought that keyup literally ment when the up key was pushed or when the downkey was pushed for keydown (like as if you were changing cells in excel).  Changing that and changing .val to .text instantly fixed my issue!!  :-)  Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad to help @Brandon!

Comment: I just realized that apparently the delete key does not count towards keyup as it is not triggering the ajax.  If you just delete the value out of the cell without replacing it, $(this).keyup(function() { is never triggered.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You would have to specifically catch the key's code, known conveniently as a [keycode](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/) but pressing the delete key in the example I provided works properly.

Comment: I believe I have what you told me to use above?  The delete and backspace keys arent being picked up though, only when I add #s, not delete them.

http://jsbin.com/wugiyeceti/edit?js,output

Comment: Your example is not working because jQuery is not defined.

Comment: Im sorry, I forgot to add that line into jsbin.  Heres the line I have in my page for that though:

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

Comment: The version of jQuery you're using supports the same delete key behavior as my example does.

Comment: I just grabbed the link for 3.1.1 to make sure to be using the most updated version and it still is not working for me.  Number or Letter keys are being detected but not the backspace or delete keys, I am not understanding why this could be.  Here is the like version so you can see that I am not crazy...   http://www.kr3ativedesign.com/GnS/schedule.php

Comment: In the example you provided there a PHP error is returned in the alert box.  Remove the AJAX componenet, fix the code, than add the AJAX back.

Comment: I fixed the error but the page still behaves the same.  I also noticed that the enter key is not being counted either

Comment: If I shared my code would you mind looking at it?  I cant seem to find any other errors anywhere.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the bandwidth available to check your code in a much more broad scope today.

Answer (score -1):

Try "delegate" instead of "bind"

Comment: jQuery's `delegate` was deprecated and removed several years ago?

Comment: if is the case, "bind" also is deprecated, see here : "Deprecated 3.0 | Events" http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: Yes it is, `on()` should be used for all events

Comment: it's still working but it will be removed in the future releases ^^, when you see Deprecated start searching for a new alternative :)

Comment: Depends on what release you use @Brandon

Comment: yes so i need just to know who down vote, how you can get more reputation, that's was my problem that's why i write an answer instead of comment pffff!! WHY Downvote get less in reputation again :(

Comment: @lefdilia it is definitely hard to build up.  I am still new to the page but I get knocked a good bit also.  I feel my questions are detailed but someone still always knocks me down for something.

Comment: You probably got downvoted because ***"try this"*** answers are not considered good answers. A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO. If you want to get the rep back you lost here you can delete the answer and you'll get your points back. Keep in mind that downvotes are not personal, only an indication of an answers usefulness. It doesn't matter 'who' did it. To get more rep continue to provide answers to questions, filled with good information and code examples. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯